# Daily average of count grouped by month

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to figure out the best way to display the daily average of a count by month.

Here is what the data looks like

```
Date(date),Location(string),UnitID(string)
2011-12-1,A,123
2011-12-1,A,456
2011-12-1,B,789
2011-12-1,B,246
2011-12-2,A,135
2011-12-2,A,123
2011-12-2,B,789
2011-12-2,B,468
...
```

We would like a report showing the following:

```
(location)   12/2011    1/2012    2/2012 (by month)
A             12.5        10.3      14.0
B             22.1        20.9      25.6
```

The summary fields should be calculated following this general idea for each month/location combination:

```
Avg(Count(UnitID))/(days in month) *see below for clarification, this formula doesn't really make much sense.
```

The Avg(Count(UnitID)) is the tough part. A cross tab would work best, but anything at this point will work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit for clarity: The data is a listing of all units that had a failure. Several Units per day fail, spread out over several locations. In English what I want is the average daily number of failures of units per month, grouped by location.

Comment: Can you clarify what that formula is doing? If you take the average of the `Count(UnitID)` by month/location, then the result will always just be the count... The Average() function won't actually be doing anything

Comment: I added a note at the bottom that hopefully will help clarify what I'm trying to do. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend doing this in a crosstab.

First, add a formula (called something like perMonthCount) like the following to the report:

```
1 / DatePart ("d", 
              DateAdd ("d", 
                       -1, 
                       DateAdd ("m", 
                                1, 
                                DateAdd ("d", 
                                         1-DatePart ("d", {failures.fail_date}),
                                         {failures.fail_date}) ) ) )
```

Next, select `Insert > Cross-Tab...` from the menu and specify the following values in the Cross-Tab tab of the Cross-Tab Expert dailog:

- Rows: your location field
- Columns: your failure date field (use the Group Options button to specify that the column should be printed `for each month`, instead of the default `for each day`.)
- Summarized Fields: the @perMonthCount formula field (the summary operation should default to `Sum of`.)

In the Customize Style tab of the Cross-Tab Expert dailog, check the Suppress Row Grand Totals tick-box. (You may also want to check the Suppress Column Grand Totals tick-box, if you don't want to see totals for all locations at the end of the report.)

Click on OK at the bottom of the Cross-Tab expert dialog and drop the Cross-Tab into the report footer.

You will also probably want to suppress the details section of your report.

At this stage, you should now be able to preview your results.

Comment: That is a really clever approach and I bet it will work. I'm out of the office until Tuesday, but I'll check it then and let you know.

I had never considered summing the reciprocal of the days in a month to get an average, but it makes sense.